# KDE Classifier: Mean of the bandwidths of features produces better results than a bandwidth for each feature. Why?

Tags: bayesian, kernel-smoothing

I'm building a Univariate Bayesian Kernel Density Estimation Classifier.

It works like the Naives Bayes Classifier but instead of using the normal density function, it uses the Kernel Density Estimation generated density function.
I calculate de bandwidth by using Sheater-Jones method.

I've tried two things:

1. Calculate the bandwidth for every feature (variable). So every feature has a different bandwidth.
2. Calculate the bandwidth for every feature and then use the mean of the bandwidths.

The first approach produces poor results (the accuracy of the classifier is just a little better than NB).
The second approach produces much better results.

The question is: why?
The second approach doesn't make sense mathematically. Every feature have a different probability density function, so it makes sense to use an individual bandwith for each different feature.

The datasets that I'm using are gene expression data. They have a lot of features (20000-55000) and few samples (20-150). They are from here: https://sbcb.inf.ufrgs.br/cumida

Thank you.

Comment: This is quite a late response, so first off; did you make any progress on this? I could think several reasons for this behavior, foremost the risk of heavily overfitting: you have a very high-dim, sparse space and so the best bandwidth on training might be minuscule and only fitting a few points perfectly. By having the test set just slightly outside these regions might result in a likelihood ≈ 0. It could make sense to try to use PCA to reduce the dimensionality quite drastically before KDE. Hopefully enough signal could be saved in a D-dim space, with D < # of samples.